# efficient way to store triplets in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, data-structures

I use SQL query and receive a long list of triplets into a variable named 'results'.
the information in the triplets is:
* hashed email (long string)
* list id (integer)
* type of list (single character, A or P)

here is an example of some of the records:

```
In[2]: for a,b,c in results:
       print a
       print b
       print c
Out[2]:978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806
       11530
       A
       978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806
       11504
       A
       c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825
       11508
       P
       c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825
       11541
       P
```

where a is an hashed email, b is list id and c is list type.

* an email can be found in more than one list 
* a list type can only be one of these two (A or P) 
Given the variable 'result', I want to arrange this data in an efficient way  where I have triplets of: 
[list id, list type, [list of emails] ]

Comment: It depends on how you are going to process or consume this data later. If there is one piece of information that is the most significant, the most efficient way to store the data is a dictionary. Otherwise, you already have a "list of triplets" (`results`)

Comment: my goal later will be to iterate on the data, one list id at a time. do a simple if-else to check the type for each list id and then iterate on the emails.

Comment: Are the list ids unique among all entries? Keep in mind it may be more efficient to change the SQL query to include a group by clause rather than post-processing in Python

Comment: We need more info on your data and how you are going to use it later in order to be able to give you a useful answer

Comment: the list id can be a part of a next template with a different email, but definitely with the same type

Comment: I need to check if the list is already in the new data structure I built, and then just add the email to the email list.

Comment: `dict` or `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the additional info in the comments I'd suggest to change the SQL query so `results` is sorted by list_id and type, then:

```
from itertools import groupby

# assume results contains the results of the SQL query and is ordered by list_id AND type
results = [('978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806', 11504, 'A'),
           ('c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825', 11508, 'P'),
           ('c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff826', 11508, 'P'),
           ('978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806', 11530, 'A'),
           ('c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825', 11541, 'P')]

output = {}

for (list_id, list_type), list_id_data in groupby(results, key=lambda data: (data[1], data[2])):
    output[list_id, list_type] = [row[0] for row in list_id_data]


print(output)
#  {(11504, 'A'): ['978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806'],
#   (11508, 'P'): ['c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825', 'c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff826'],
#   (11530, 'A'): ['978a0eefffeb11b0890afe7066154806'],
#   (11541, 'P'): ['c445fb5c367a18f406f96847e02ff825']}
```

`output` is a dictionary  whose keys are `(list_id, type)` tuples and values are lists of email addresses.

If you feel like ruining someone's day in production the above loop can be written as a comprehension:

```
output = {(list_id, list_type): [row[0] for row in list_id_data]
          for (list_id, list_type), list_id_data in groupby(results, key=lambda data: (data[1], data[2]))}
```

I don't know *how* you are querying the database. If you are using a DAL that allows getting each row as a dictionary and not a tuple then the above can be written in a less confusing manner (using names instead of indexes, ie `data[1], data[2], row[0]`)